# Getting error Transaction does not exist/is not available when not adding sginer to wallet via web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount()?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

Getting error

> Transaction does not exist/is not available

when not adding sginer to wallet via web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount() ?

**What is the working of line?**

```
const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(configData.user[userName].key);
        web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer);
```

Why I get the above error when I comment **web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer);** ?
Where is this transaction getting signed?

```
const mintToken = async (body) => {
    try {
        const { userName, to, quantity } = body;


        const { web3 } = await getContract();
        const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(configData.user[userName].key);
        web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer);
       
        // const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(configData.abi, configData.contractAddress, { from: configData.user[userName].account });
        const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(configData.abi, configData.contractAddress, { from: configData.user[userName].account });
        const tx = contract.methods._mint(to, quantity);
        const { gasLimit, gasPrice } = await getGasPrice_Limit(web3);
        let txURL;

        const receipt = await tx.send({
            from: configData.user[userName].account,
            // from: signer.address,
            gas: await tx.estimateGas(),
            gasLimit,
            gasPrice
        }).once("transactionHash", (txhash) => {
            console.log(`Mining transaction ...`);
            txURL = `https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/${txhash}`
            console.log(`https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/${txhash}`);
        });

        const msg = `${quantity} tokens were minted successully for address: ${to}.`;
        console.log(msg);
        console.log(`Mined! You block number: ${receipt.blockNumber}`);
        return {
            status: true,
            txURL,
            blockNumber: receipt.blockNumber,
            msg
        } 
    } catch (error) {
        error = error.message.substring(35).trim().replace("'", "")
        console.log(`[ERR] ${error}`)
        return {
            status: false,
            errMsg: error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a transaction, web3js signs it with the default account from the wallet or with an address that you specified that is in the wallet.

In your case, I see that you are calling '_mint' method (just by naming I assume that this method is private so you can't really call it, developers usually add underscore to private methods) and you are calling transaction to send. In both places, web3js signs the transaction.

Comment: What can be the solution for this, where I need not to add signers again and again to my wallet before doing any transaction.

Comment: You shoud initialize your provider and do
`web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer);`
somewhere else

For example, create file provider.js from where you export `new Web3()`.
And now you can import your provider anywhere in the app and it will be the same instance everywhere (a singleton).
So now, you can create some function called `addMainSigner` where you do `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer);` where web3 is your imported provider. You just call it once on start and it will be stored in your provider and used to sign transactions.